# HSQLDB does not work when running from JSP, but works when running the Java code alone

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jdbc, hsqldb

I'm currently working on a small project for my own learning purposes, where there is a database and a JSP page to access that database. I have a Java EE project on my Eclipse and I am using the following:

- Tomcat 9
- HSQLDB
- Java JDK 15.0.1
- Eclipse

When running the Java code below alone, it works and I get the output I want:

#### shop.RDB

```
package shop;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class RDB 
{
  private Connection con;
  
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
      try 
      {
          RDB test = new RDB();
          Collection<Product> ProductsInDB = test.getAllProducts();
      
          for (Product p : ProductsInDB)
          {
              System.out.println(p.toString());
          }
          test.shutdown();
      }
      catch(SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
  }

  public RDB() 
  {
    try 
    {
      Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:shopDB;hsqldb.lock_file=false", "sa",  "");
      System.out.println("Created con");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { 
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
    }
  }

  public Collection<Product> getAllProducts()
  {
      return getProductCollection("Select * from Product");
  }
  
  public Collection<Product> getProductCollection(String query) 
  {
      LinkedList<Product> list = new LinkedList<Product>();
      try {
          Statement s = con.createStatement();

          ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(query);
          while (rs.next())
          {
              Product product = new Product(
                      rs.getString("PID"),
                      rs.getString("name"),                                        
                      rs.getDouble("price")                );
              list.add(product);
          }
          return list;
      }
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
          System.out.println("Exception in getProducts(): " + e);
          return null;
      }
  }
  
  public void shutdown() throws SQLException
  {

      Statement st = con.createStatement();

      // db writes out to files and performs clean shuts down
      // otherwise there will be an unclean shutdown
      // when program ends
      st.execute("SHUTDOWN");
      con.close();    // if there are no other open connection
  }
}
```

However, when I try to do the exactly the same thing and present the data on a .jsp file, it does not work:

#### ProductList.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType = "text/html;charset=UTF-8" language = "java" %>
<%@ page import = "shop.Product, shop.RDB, java.sql.*, java.util.Collection" %>

<html>

    <head>  <title>Amazonius Shop</title>  </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <h3>Using Database</h3>
        
        <table>
        
            <tr style = "color: red">
            <th> ID </th>  <th> Product </th>  <th> Price </th>
            </tr>
            
            <%
                try {
                    RDB DB = new RDB();
                    Collection<Product> ProductsInDB = DB.getAllProducts();
                
                    for (Product p : ProductsInDB) 
                    {
            %>          
            <tr style = "color: blue">
                <td> <%= p.PID %> </td>
                <td> <%= p.name %> </td>
                <td> <%= p.price %> </td>
            </tr>
            
            <%      } 
                    DB.shutdown();
                }
                catch(SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            %>
            
        </table>
    
    </body>

</html>
```

- shop is the package in Java resources folder
- Product is a custom data structure.
- ProductList is the JSP file inside WebContent folder

#### And gives this error:

```
Mar 15, 2021 10:22:36 AM org.hsqldb.persist.Logger logInfoEvent
INFO: Database closed
Exception: java.sql.SQLException: file input/output error: shopDB.log
Mar 15, 2021 10:22:36 AM org.hsqldb.persist.Logger logSevereEvent
SEVERE: could not reopen database
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: file input/output error: shopDB.log
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.openLog(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at shop.RDB.<init>(RDB.java:32)
    at org.apache.jsp.lab6web.ProductList_jsp._jspService(ProductList_jsp.java:183)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:326)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Exception in getProducts(): java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()" because "this.con" is null
Mar 15, 2021 10:22:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Education_Tests_Project] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [lab6web/ProductList.jsp] at line [50]

47:                     RDB DB = new RDB();
48:                     Collection<Product> ProductsInDB = DB.getAllProducts();
49:                 
50:                     for (Product p : ProductsInDB) 
51:                     {
52:             %>          
53:             <tr style = "color: blue">


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Collection.iterator()" because "ProductsInDB" is null
    at org.apache.jsp.lab6web.ProductList_jsp._jspService(ProductList_jsp.java:186)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:326)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

The server works fine for other kind of JSP code. In addition, I have my hsqldb.jar in Tomcat's lib folder (saw from a tutorial) and Tomcat is in the Java build path. I've tried several things like;

- Putting the .jar file in Java build path
- Putting .jar in Java bin and lib folder both separately and simultaneously
- Putting .jar in WEB-INF lib folder (saw from a website)

And every attempt keeps giving the same error.

### Additional Information

#### shop.Product

```
package shop;

public class Product
{
    public String PID;
    public String name;
    public double price;
    
    public Product(String PID, String name, double price)
    {
        this.PID = PID;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
        return name + "\t " + price;
    }

}
```

#### Java Build Path

[image: Java build path in project properties]

Comment: Given the error `org.hsqldb.HsqlException: file input/output error: shopDB.log`, I guess that there is a problem creating or reading the database, could be a permission issue. As an aside, don't catch exceptions and continue on as if nothing happens; in this case that causes the secondary `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection URL is the problem. On Tomcat or other app servers, directories are typically read-only and you cannot create the database there. See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_variables_url on how to point to your home directory or a directory that is defined in Tomcat properties as the data directory. You shouldn't use the `hsqldb.lock_file=false` on the URL as this is not recommended for normal usage. The example below uses the home directory for the database location.

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:~/shopDB", "sa",  "");
```

Comment: It was saying _Database lock acquisition failure_ that's why I included that. Tried your answer but then it said _user lacks privilege or object not found error_ but the good thing was it created the connection. Then I tried it with the full path of the database (excluding `hsqldb.lock_file=false` ) and it worked. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong every configuration seems fine. But since it created the connection, your answer is relevant for the context of my question so thank you.

Comment: The lock acquisition failure means either it cannot create the .lck file because the directory is read-only, or the database is already open by another process. You obviously want to avoid this, so it's not a good idea to disable the lock file.

Comment: Yes I realized it's not a good idea after some research, thank you. But still I don't get that why it doesn't work 100% properly when I don't write the full path since .jsp files and database are in the same directory.